# C# WinForms - DragDrop within the same TreeViewControl

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, treeview

I'm attempting to implement a DragDrop of a treeview item within the same control.

I want to be able to move an item from 1 node to another.

Here is my current code, When I run this I can see the item has started the drag but the windows icon will not allow it to be dropped to any nodes on the Control.

**My current code**

```
private void treeView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void treeView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void treeView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TreeNode)))
    {
        TreeNode sourceNode = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeView)) as TreeNode;

        var item = new TreeNode(sourceNode.Text);


        System.Drawing.Point pt = ((TreeView)sender).PointToClient(new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y));
        TreeNode DestinationNode = ((TreeView)sender).GetNodeAt(pt);

        DestinationNode.Nodes.Add(item);
        DestinationNode.Expand();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just modify `treeView1_DragDrop` function to:

```cs
private void treeView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve the client coordinates of the drop location.
    Point targetPoint = treeView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    // Retrieve the node at the drop location.
    TreeNode targetNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);

    // Retrieve the node that was dragged.
    TreeNode draggedNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));

    // Confirm that the node at the drop location is not 
    // the dragged node and that target node isn't null
    // (for example if you drag outside the control)
    if (!draggedNode.Equals(targetNode) && targetNode != null)
    {
        // Remove the node from its current 
        // location and add it to the node at the drop location.
        draggedNode.Remove();
        targetNode.Nodes.Add(draggedNode);

        // Expand the node at the location 
        // to show the dropped node.
        targetNode.Expand();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know @Francesco B. was solving this persons specific problem, but thought I'd add, inserting the following line at the top of the function " TreeView treeView1 = (TreeView) sender; " it becomes a little more reusable.

Comment: Note that if you have created your own TreeNode class, you have to use that type name in the call to e.Data.GetData, or draggedNode will become null.

Answer (score 18):

Set `AllowDrop=true` on the tree control.

Comment: had to fix my reply, I did forget to set the AllowDrop however it still isnt working :( - Im making some adjustments and may update my post soon

Answer (score 5):

A few more improvements and additions to the DragDrop handler to go along with all the other revisions.

Added Support:

- Supports dropping nodes onto the treeview background (at bottom). Nodes get added to the bottom of the tree.
- Incorporated the "don't drop on child node" example by mrpurple and groomed it so it's inline with the original example.
- Also made it so the dragged node gets selected after it's dropped. Recommend loading the content for the dropped node here as well otherwise the
  user could become confused by what's currently showing vs what node is selected.

Note: Be sure and AllowDrop=true on the treeview control otherwise you can't drop nodes.

```
private void treeView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void treeView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void treeView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve the client coordinates of the drop location.
    Point targetPoint = treeView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    // Retrieve the node at the drop location.
    TreeNode targetNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);

    // Retrieve the node that was dragged.
    TreeNode draggedNode = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));

    // Sanity check
    if (draggedNode == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Did the user drop on a valid target node?
    if (targetNode == null)
    {
        // The user dropped the node on the treeview control instead
        // of another node so lets place the node at the bottom of the tree.
        draggedNode.Remove();
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(draggedNode);
        draggedNode.Expand();
    }
    else
    {
        TreeNode parentNode = targetNode;

        // Confirm that the node at the drop location is not 
        // the dragged node and that target node isn't null
        // (for example if you drag outside the control)
        if (!draggedNode.Equals(targetNode) && targetNode != null)
        {
            bool canDrop = true;

            // Crawl our way up from the node we dropped on to find out if
            // if the target node is our parent. 
            while (canDrop && (parentNode != null))
            {
                canDrop = !Object.ReferenceEquals(draggedNode, parentNode);
                parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
            }

            // Is this a valid drop location?
            if (canDrop)
            {
                // Yes. Move the node, expand it, and select it.
                draggedNode.Remove();
                targetNode.Nodes.Add(draggedNode);
                targetNode.Expand();
            }
        }
    }

    // Optional: Select the dropped node and navigate (however you do it)
    treeView1.SelectedNode = draggedNode;
    // NavigateToContent(draggedNode.Tag);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

slightly improved version that prevents you dropping a node onto itself *or any of its descendants*

```
private void treeView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode draggedNode = (MatfloNode)drgevent.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));

    Point pt = this.PointToClient(new System.Drawing.Point(drgevent.X, drgevent.Y));
    TreeNode targetNode = this.GetNodeAt(pt);

    TreeNode parentNode = targetNode;

    if (draggedNode != null &&
        targetNode != null  )
    {
        bool canDrop = true;
        while (canDrop && (parentNode != null))
        {
            canDrop = !Object.ReferenceEquals(draggedNode, parentNode);
            parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
        }

        if (canDrop)
        {
            draggedNode.Remove();
            targetNode.Nodes.Add(draggedNode);
            targetNode.Expand();
        }
    }
}
```